# p:blockUI / pe:blockUI: Why doesn't it work in my simple example?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

**I would like to hide an element while a button triggered action is being performed:**

```
<h:form id="sendtxform">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder">      
            <pe:blockUI block="input" widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
            LOADING<br />
                <p:graphicImage name="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </pe:blockUI>

            <p:commandButton id="command" value="ISSUE APP"
                actionListener="#{transactionXmlController.getTxDataPredefined}"
                ajax="true" update="growl,input"
                onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block();"
                oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock();">
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:inputTextarea id="input" cols="150" rows="30" autoResize="false"
                value="#{transactionXmlEditableModel.xml}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

I tried with p:blockUI / pe:blockUI and with/without the onstart and oncomplete attributes.

What am I doig wrong ? I use blockUI somewhere else, and it is working fine:

The only difference is that the table is its own trigger.

I followed [this](http://www.journaldev.com/3413/primefaces-blockui-component-example-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: The panelgrid you mean? Did you try putting it outside the panelGrid and see if you can trigger it then? And what version are you using?

Comment: I wanted to block the inputTextArea, but the grid is fine too. But it does not works. I did what you suggested. As before, nothing happens. I am using Primefaces Version 6

Comment: I think you are mixing p:blockUI and pe:blockUI, The primefaces extensions component hasn't the block attribute, use target instead

Comment: does it work if you 'target' an input instead of an inputTextarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block the input seems to not work, you can wrap the input with a panel and block it.

PrimeFaces Extensions:

```
<h:form id="sendtxform">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder">
        <pe:blockUI target="panel" widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
        LOADING<br />
            <p:graphicImage name="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </pe:blockUI>

        <p:commandButton id="command" value="ISSUE APP"
            actionListener="#{transactionXmlController.getTxDataPredefined}"
            ajax="true" update="input"
            onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block();"
            oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock();">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:panel id="panel">
            <p:inputTextarea id="input" cols="150" rows="30" autoResize="false"
            value="#{transactionXmlEditableModel.xml}" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

PrimeFaces:

```
<h:form id="sendtxform">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder">
        <p:blockUI block="panel" trigger="command">
        LOADING<br />
            <p:graphicImage name="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </p:blockUI>

        <p:commandButton id="command" value="ISSUE APP"
            actionListener="#{transactionXmlController.getTxDataPredefined}"
            ajax="true" update="input">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:panel id="panel">
            <p:inputTextarea id="input" cols="150" rows="30" autoResize="false"
            value="#{transactionXmlEditableModel.xml}" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Are we using different versions ? (2.2 for me)

Comment: I've just tried and it works, i use jsf 2.2, pf 6 e pfe 6. Have you error in js console?

Comment: I saw in your code that you have block attribute. PF extensions hasn't that attribute, use target.

Comment: I am having problems with the PF Extensions. I'd be happy about a solution with p:blockUI.

Comment: I added the pf solution

Comment: @SiMag: does it work if target an inputText instead of inputTextarea?

Comment: @SiMag: Thanks ! kuketje: I Did. I have problems with my primefaces extensions namespace (hence the error). SiMag made me realize my error the the "target" attribute. Problem solved :)

Comment: @Kukeltje using inputText or inputTextArea as target doesn't work, the show/hide functions of blockui are called but the block isn't visible, maybe is a style issue